# how to re-texture armor with transparency

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was making my own texture pack and I fell into a problem. I was changing the texture pack of the diamond armor, and then I wanted it to have transparency so I went to GIMP(a photo editing software) and made this
[image]

I replaced the old texture with the new one. then I made the texture pack and added it to Minecraft. nowhere is the problem, when I wear the diamond armor the transparency doesn't work and you can still see the diamond armor under it
[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Transparency works perfectly fine for me.

#### (Note: I'm no artist and this was for testing purposes)

I used this for my 'diamond_layer_1.png':
[image: red scribble]

And it worked correctly (without armor on for reference):

[image: my skin normally][image: my skin with a red scribble on it]

Layer 2 is used solely for the leggings, as far as I can tell.

I'm not sure why yours would keep the original texture, but make sure the 'transparent' pixels actually have 0 opacity. I use paint.NET for my image editing, so I don't know how GIMP works exactly. If you want, download the scribble I used and edit it making sure to preserve the alpha channel (save as png)